# List of custom variables that can be accessed inside a static block

Tags: blocks, magento2.4, variables, custom-variable

What I want to do is inject variables into static blocks. I know this can be achieved in `System -> Custom Variables` but it wouldn't be any quicker than opening up every static block to change the values at the moment. I was thinking of something like a file with a list of variables would be faster and easier to maintain. I'm not sure how this can be done in Magento 2. I've looked at some complex suggestions but I'm still not clear which would be the best way. I want to achieve this in the simplest way possible. Preferably a file that can be added to my custom theme directory.